# Random.Range in Unity3D is not giving numbers in the range given

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So, I'm trying to find a random number between -58.6 and 156.18. I want to put that number into a y value when moving the position of a canvas object. Here's my code: This code is on a canvas object

```
using UnityEngine;
public class LaserControl : MonoBehaviour {
    public Transform player;
    public Transform laserStart;
    void Start () {
        //change to 20 and 35

        InvokeRepeating("ShowFork", 5, 10);
    }

    private void ShowFork()
    {

// look at the line below:

        transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x,Random.Range(-58.6f ,156.18f),0);
        GetComponent<CanvasGroup>().alpha = 1;
        Invoke("Fire", 3);
    }
    private void Fire() {
        Vector3 screenPoint = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(transform.position.x-laserStart.position.x,transform.position.y,0));
        float y = screenPoint.y;
        laserStart.transform.position = new Vector3(screenPoint.x, y, laserStart.position.z);
        laserStart.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().enabled = true;
        laserStart.GetComponent<ShootBeam>().enabled = true;
        Invoke("Revert", 3);
    }
    private void Revert()
    {
        GetComponent<CanvasGroup>().alpha = 0;
        laserStart.GetComponent<ShootBeam>().enabled = true;
    }
}
```

Anyway, so when that happens, I get values that aren't in the range.

Here's one of them: -111.9216

I don't understand why this would happen, as I've never encountered problems with the simple Random.Range method before. It's probably some really simple problem though, I'm new to Unity. Please help! Thanks!

Comment: Considering you are newbie, i would suggest you to capture "Random.Range(-58.6f ,156.18f)" into variable (randomValue for instance) and use "Debug.Log(randomValue)" to print values. Let me know if the values printed will still be out of range

Comment: You know that the position displayed in the Inspector always is in **local** space, right? So when you set the `position` (in global space) it might gain an unexpected offset to it's parent object resulting in different values. Try `transform.localPosition = ...` and see if this fixes your problem ;)

Comment: @derHugo Should be an answer, I'd mark it as accepted! Thanks! It worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all:

The position displayed in the Unity Inspector is always the **local Space** offset to the according parent object.

Thus when assigning a new `transform.position` in **global/absolute World-Space** there will always be a different local-space offset if the parent object's transformations are different from the default

- position: `0,0,0`
- rotation: `0,0,0`
- scale: `1,1,1`

So what you should do is assign and access the [`localPosition`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-localPosition.html) coordinates instead:

```
transform.localPosition = new Vector3(transform.localPosition.x,Random.Range(-58.6f ,156.18f),0);
```

---

Besides that you are repeatedly calling `GetComponent` which is quite expensive. You should rather initialize your component and get all required references **once**, store them and reuse them later:

```
public Transform player;
public Transform laserStart;

// Of possible already reference these via the Inspector
// Then you could skip the GetComponent entirely
[SerializeField] private CanvasGroup _canvasGroup;
[SerializeField] private SpriteRenderer _laserSpriteRenderer;
[SerializeField] private ShootBeam _laserShootBeam;

// Top secret hint for you ;)
// simply go to the ContextMenu of this component and hit FetchComponents
// Then you don't have to manually reference them.
[ContextMenu (nameof(FetchComponents))]
void FetchComponents() 
{
    if(!_canvasGroup) _canvasGroup = GetComponent<CanvasGroup>();
    if(!_laserSpriteRenderer) _laserSpriteRenderer = laserStart.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
    if(!_laserShootBeam) _laserShootBeam = laserStart.GetComponent<ShootBeam>();
}

private void Start()
{
    FetchComponents();

    //change to 20 and 35
    InvokeRepeating(nameof(ShowFork), 5, 10);
}

private void ShowFork()
{
    transform.localPosition = new Vector3(transform.localPosition.x,Random.Range(-58.6f ,156.18f),0);
    _canvasGroup.alpha = 1;
    Invoke(nameof(Fire), 3);
}

private void Fire()
{
    var screenPoint = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(transform.position.x-laserStart.position.x, transform.position.y, 0));
    laserStart.transform.position = new Vector3(screenPoint.x, screenPoint.y, laserStart.position.z);
    _laserSpriteRenderer.enabled = true;
    _laserShootBeam.enabled = true;
    Invoke(nameof(Revert), 3);
}

private void Revert()
{
    _canvasGroup.alpha = 0;

    // TODO: I thought you want to revert here?
    _laserShootBeam.enabled = true;
}
```

---

In general using `Invoke` is fine and often a good alternative but in your case it can get quite confusing and you have to be careful with your timings. Here I would rather suggest to use a [Coroutine](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html):

```
private void Start()
{
    FetchComponents();
    StartCoroutine(LaserRoutine());
}

private IEnumerator LaserRoutine()
{
    //change to 20 and 35
    // initial wait
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(5.0f);

    // this looks very scary but is fine in a Coroutine
    // as long as you yield somewhere inside!
    while(true)
    {
        // Your former ShowFork
        transform.localPosition = new Vector3(transform.localPosition.x,Random.Range(-58.6f ,156.18f),0);
        _canvasGroup.alpha = 1;

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(3.0f);

        // Your former Fire
        var screenPoint = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(transform.position.x-laserStart.position.x, transform.position.y, 0));
        laserStart.position = new Vector3(screenPoint.x, screenPoint.y, laserStart.position.z);
        _laserSpriteRenderer.enabled = true;
        _laserShootBeam.enabled = true;

        yield return new WaitForSeconds (3.0f);

        // Your former Revert

        _canvasGroup.alpha = 0;

        // TODO: I thought you want to revert here?
        _laserShootBeam.enabled = false;
        _laserSpriteRenderer.enabled = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: You're awesome @derHugo ! Thanks for the great coding techniques!